# Apache Thrift, Thread Safe TSimpleServer stop() call

Tags: c++, synchronization, thread-safety, thrift

I'm using the Thrift framework to handle IPC between a couple of apps.

There seems to be a slight race condition issue that I want to solve, but there is also a thread safety issue that has sprung up with this solution.

TSimpleServer (Thrift code) has code that looks like this:

```
void TSimpleServer::serve()
{
   // ...
   while(!stop_) { // ... }
}

void TSimpleServer::stop()
{
   stop_ = true;
   // ...
}
```

So if I launch a new thread that runs this function:

```
void workerFunction()
{
   // server is of type TSimpleServer
   server.serve();  // blocks here
}
```

And try stopping it from a different thread:

```
void StopServer()
{
   server.stop();  // called from a separate thread
}
```

Isn't it possible that the thread running serve() can read from the unprotected stop_ property of TSimpleServer while the thread from stop() is writing to it?

Is this a non-issue for some reason I'm overlooking? Any help on synchronizing this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be an issue. Any write to a property-aligned variable that fits processor word (4 or 8 bytes) is atomic. In other words it's impossible to read its value WHILE another thread is writing to it. So, the code is perfectly correct.

Comment: I see, so stop_ = true translates to an atomic series of assembly calls?

Comment: In any case, the while loop will always either read a `true` or a `false` value, so there isn't really anything that can go wrong. Problems would only arise if you for instance had to in- or decrement a value, which requires both a read and a write to do.